# compare to object based on one object key and other object value and push result to new array using map function?

Tags: javascript

I have two array of object I want to compare one object value with other object key and push result to third array. please help...

```
arr1 = [
{head: "first_name", value:"First Name"}, 
{head: "last_name", value:"Last Name"}, 
{head: "age", value:"Age"}];

arr2 = [
{car:"aa", xyz:"asdsa", abc:"dsds",first_name: "Jack", last_name: "Dan", age:"25"},
{car:"bb", xyz:"asdsa", abc:"dsds",first_name: "Mark", last_name: "Wood", age:"28"},
{car:"cc", xyz:"asdsa", abc:"dsds",first_name: "Carl", last_name: "R", age:"25"},
{ car:"dd", xyz:"asdsa", abc:"dsds",first_name: "Max", last_name: "P", age:"25"}
]

arr1.map(el=> {
arr2.map(elm => {
if(el.head === elm.object.key){
arr3.push(elm)
}
})
})

Expected output:
arr3 = arr2 = [
{first_name: "Jack", last_name: "Dan", age:"25"},
{first_name: "Mark", last_name: "Wood", age:"28"},
{first_name: "Carl", last_name: "R", age:"25"},
{first_name: "Max", last_name: "P", age:"25"}
]
```

Comment: 1. Don't use `map` when you're writing `forEach` code. 2. There is no `elm.object` 3. you have to map over `arr2`, using `Object.values(arr1)` to compose the new object (you're simply pushing to a new array, but the objects you want don't exist yet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the logic in an immutable  way. Tested and works fine.

```
const arr3 = arr2.map((item) => {
  const keys = arr1.map((keyObject) => keyObject.head);
  return keys.reduce((mem, key) => {
    mem[key] = item[key];
    return mem
  }, {})
})
```

Here is the snapshot of the output executed in the console.

[image: Snapshot of output]

Comment: May I know as to why it's voted down?. It produces the exact expected result.

Comment: the resulting output has all the key value pair as in arr2, I want only 3 key value pair that too in same order. Can u please chk the expected output

Comment: @VishnuShenoy - I have attached a snapshot of the output I got by running the above code. It seem to have only the expected keys and not all the keys. 
Are you sure the code did not produce the expected result?

Comment: i have given one up, the resulting value is in arr3 right

Comment: I have edited and added `const arr3 = ` to the result. Now the result will be in `arr3`. Hope am right. Kindly let me know.

Comment: The answer to order the keys is available here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467129/sort-javascript-object-by-key

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218887/discussion-between-vasanth-gopal-and-vishnu-shenoy).